# Release connection after use, connection pool Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am wondering where the connection should be released after using it, i have seen couple of options for that:

```
pool.getConnection(function(err, conn){

    //conn.release() // should be placed here (1)?
    conn.query(query, function(err, result){

       //conn.release() // should be placed here (2)?
       if(!err){
           //conn.release() // should be placed here (3)?
       }
       else{
           //conn.release() // should be placed here (4)?
       }
       //conn.release() // should be placed here (5)?
    });

    //conn.release() // should be placed here (6)?

});
```

Or maybe should it be released both error and non error cases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct place is either #2 or #5.

You want to release the connection when you are done using it.

#6 would be wrong because `query()` is asynchronous, so it would return right away before the connection is done with the query and before the callback fires. So you'd be releasing the connection before you are done with it.

#5 is correct because the callback has fired and you have done everything you are going to do with it. Note that this assumes that you do not use `return` to exit the function before that point. (Some people do that in their `if (err)` blocks.)

#2 is also correct if you aren't using the connection anywhere inside the callback. If you *are* using it in the callback, then you don't want to release it before you are done using it.

#3 and #4 are incorrect unless you use *both* of them. Otherwise, you are only releasing the connection in some situtations.

And #1 is incorrect because you haven't used the connection yet.